# Adding Authorize Headers and validate in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, authorization

In my ASP.Net Web API Project, i added `[Authorize]` attribute to the controller. So when i call the method it is returning error as

```
"Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
```

How to send `Authorize` Headers along with my request.

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Settings(SettingModel data)
{
    --Do i need to check authorize headers manually here?
    --code goes here
}
```

*Here it is called*

```
http://localhost/sample/api/Settings

Headers
{
   Content-Type: application/json
   Authorization: What value need to be send here?
}
```

Comment: when you say token based authorization, do you mean JWT from Identity Server, probably version 4, or are you using something else?

Answer (score 0):

check the answers of Darin : [How to do role based authorization for asp.net mvc 4 web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986974/how-to-do-role-based-authorization-for-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api)

I guess you need to register the handler..

Comment: I think u posted different answer. I just need here is token based authorization. Something token i need to issue on login and the subsequent request must include that token...