# How can I safely set the user principal in a custom WebAPI HttpMessageHandler?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-web-api

For basic authentication I have implemented a custom `HttpMessageHandler` based on the example shown in Darin Dimitrov's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11536349/270591

The code creates an instance `principal` of type `GenericPrincipal` with user name and roles and then sets this principal to the current principal of the thread:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
```

Later in a `ApiController` method the principal can be read by accessing the controllers `User` property:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(TestModel model)
    {
        var user = User; // this should be the principal set in the handler
        //...
    }
}
```

This seemed to work fine until I recently added a custom `MediaTypeFormatter` that uses the `Task` library like so:

```
public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream,
    HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // some formatting happens and finally a TestModel is returned,
        // simulated here by just an empty model
        return (object)new TestModel();
    });
    return task;
}
```

(I have this approach to start a task with `Task.Factory.StartNew` in `ReadFromStreamAsync` from some sample code. Is it wrong and maybe the only reason for the problem?)

Now, "sometimes" - and for me it appears to be random - the `User` principal in the controller method isn't the principal anymore I've set in the MessageHandler, i.e. user name, `Authenticated` flag and roles are all lost. The reason seems to be that the custom MediaTypeFormatter causes a change of the thread between MessageHandler and controller method. I've confirmed this by comparing the values of `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` in the MessageHandler and in the controller method. "Sometimes" they are different and then the principal is "lost".

I've looked now for an alternative to setting `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to somehow transfer the principal safely from the custom MessageHandler to the controller method and in [this blog post](http://sixgun.co.uk/blog/2012/02/29/asp-net-web-api-basic-authentication/) request properties are used:

```
request.Properties.Add(HttpPropertyKeys.UserPrincipalKey,
    new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[0]));
```

I wanted to test that but it seems that the `HttpPropertyKeys` class (which is in namespace `System.Web.Http.Hosting`) doesn't have a `UserPrincipalKey` property anymore in the recent WebApi versions (release candidate and final release from last week as well).

My question is: How can I change the last code snippet above so that is works with the current WebAPI version? Or generally: How can I set the user principal in a custom MessageHandler and access it reliably in a controller method?

**Edit**

It is mentioned [here](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/03/08/asp-net-webapi-security-2-identity-architecture/) that "`HttpPropertyKeys.UserPrincipalKey` ... resolves to `“MS_UserPrincipal”`", so I tried to use:

```
request.Properties.Add("MS_UserPrincipal",
    new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[0]));
```

But it doesn't work as I expected: The `ApiController.User` property does not contain the principal added to the `Properties` collection above.

Comment: I suggest looking at this https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The problem of losing the principal on a new thread is mentioned here:

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/06/25/important-setting-the-client-principal-in-asp-net-web-api/

> **Important: Setting the Client Principal in ASP.NET Web API**
>
> Due to some unfortunate mechanisms buried deep in ASP.NET, setting
>   Thread.CurrentPrincipal in Web API web hosting is not enough.
>
> When hosting in ASP.NET, Thread.CurrentPrincipal might get overridden
>   with HttpContext.Current.User when creating new threads. This means
>   you have to set the principal on both the thread and the HTTP context.

And here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/264

> Today, you will need to set both of the following for user principal
>   if you use a custom message handler to perform authentication in the
>   web hosted scenario.
>
> ```
> IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(
>     new GenericIdentity("myuser"), new string[] { "myrole" });
> Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
> HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
> ```

I have added the last line `HttpContext.Current.User = principal` (needs `using System.Web;`) to the message handler and the `User` property in the `ApiController` does always have the correct principal now, even if the thread has changed due to the task in the MediaTypeFormatter.

**Edit**

Just to emphasize it: Setting the current user's principal of the `HttpContext` is only necessary when the WebApi is hosted in ASP.NET/IIS. For self-hosting it is not necessary (and not possible because `HttpContext` is an ASP.NET construct and doesn't exist when self hosted).

Answer (score 5):

To avoid the context switch try using a `TaskCompletionSource<object>` instead of manually starting another task in your custom `MediaTypeFormatter`:

```
public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    // some formatting happens and finally a TestModel is returned,
    // simulated here by just an empty model
    var testModel = new TestModel();

    tcs.SetResult(testModel);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: It works, but I'm a bit worried to have to be that careful with the usage of tasks and threads to keep a security feature intact. I've found another solution, see my own answer here.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, I have installed the RTM of vs 2012 and latest bits of asp.net web api and HttpPropertyKeys.UserPrincipalKey gives syntax error. viewing class in object browser shows that this key is not present in final release. Any ideas what else can i use?

Comment: Why do you want to use `HttpPropertyKeys.UserPrincipalKey`? Where in my answer did you see using it? So don't use it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, doesn't doing this defeat explicit threading of the Async? I.e. original code runs the task on a pool thread. Isn't there a different approach to preserve the context?

Answer (score 5):

Using your custom MessageHandler you could add the `MS_UserPrincipal` property by calling the `HttpRequestMessageExtensionMethods.SetUserPrincipal` extension method defined in `System.ServiceModel.Channels`:

```
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var user = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("UserID"), null);
    request.SetUserPrincipal(user);
    return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
```

Note that this only adds this property to the Request's Properties collection, it doesn't change the User attached to the ApiController.