# Task's continuation (built by async/await) is running on main thread in a WPF application, but on child in a console application

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task, async-await

Assume I have a simple `C#` Console Application:

```
class Program
{
    static async void func()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "main";
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "child";
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        });
        Console.WriteLine("continuation is running on {0} thread", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        func();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

When 5000 ms pass, we see the "continuation is running on child thread" message. When another 5000 ms pass, main thread finishes its work and application is closed. It looks rather logical: asynchronous task and its continuation are running on the same child thread.

But assume now I have a simple `WPF` application:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async private void mainWnd_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "main";
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "child";
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        });
        this.Title = string.Format("continuation is running on {0} thread", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }

    private void mainWnd_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Now when we press left mouse button and 5000 ms pass, we see "continuation is running on main thread" title. Moreover, if we press left button and then right button, application first will run `mainWnd_MouseLeftButtonDown` handler, then `mainWnd_MouseRightButtonDown` handler (on main thread), main thread will sleep for 10000 ms, and then continuation of asynchronous task from `mainWnd_MouseLeftButtonDown` will be still performed on main thread.

Why does `async-await` mechanism differ for these two situations?

I know that in `WPF` method can be explicitly run on UI thread through `Dispatcher.Invoke`, but `async-await` mechanism isn't `WPF`-specific, so its behavior should be equal in any kind of application, shouldn't it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`async-await` respects the current scope's [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx). That means that the context (if it exists) is captured when the asynchronous operation starts and when it ends the continuation is scheduled on the captured context.

`UI` applications (`WPF`/`Winforms`) use a `SynchronizationContext` that allows only for the main (`UI`) thread to interact with the `UI` elements, so it seamlessly works with `async-await`.

`ASP.Net` also has it's own `SynchronizationContext` called [`AspNetSynchronizationContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12659851/885318) (surprisingly). So it isn't necessarily about `UI` or [Single Thread Apartments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127240/885318).

---

If you want to disable that useful `SynchronizationContext` capturing you just need to use [`ConfigureAwait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "child";
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

More on SynchronizationContexts: [It's All About the SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx)