# Where do 'awaited' tasks execute?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

Consider the following:

```
private async void btnSlowPoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await DoItAsync();
}

private async Task<int> SomeLongJobAsync()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 999999; x++)
    {
        //ponder my existence for one second
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    return 42;
}

public async Task<int> DoItAsync()
{
    Console.Write("She'll be coming round the mountain");
    Task<int> t = SomeLongJobAsync();  //<--On what thread does this execute?
    Console.WriteLine(" when she comes.");
    return await t;
}
```

1. The first Write in `DoItAsync()` executes.
2. `SomeLongJobAsync()` starts.
3. The `WriteLine` in `DoItAsync()` executes.
4. `DoItAsync()` pauses while `SomeLongJobAsync()` works away until it's done.
5. `SomeLongJobAsync()` completes, so `DoItAsync()` returns.

Meanwhile, the UI is responsive.

On what thread does `SomeLongJobAsync()` execute?

Comment: Are you referring to a GUI application? or asking in general?

Comment: Where doesn't sound like the correct wording, as where sounds like the answer would be *on a processor on the machine the assembly is on*.

Comment: There seems to be some discrepancy among these answers. Summoning Stephen Cleary. Mr. Cleary can you hear me?

Comment: I already upvoted @I3arnon. His answer is IMO a bit confusing about how `async` methods resume on a captured context, but it is essentially correct. The key is that there is no *code* to run for a "delay", so nothing is running during the delay (and no thread is needed); the only parts of the code that *run* are the bits in-between (i.e., incrementing the `for` loop variable and checking it), and those parts run on a captured context.

Comment: @StephenCleary What about Ned's answer? Doesn't it show it executing on a threadpool thread?

Comment: It's not *always* on a threadpool thread. If you run this code in a Console app, then it will be; but if you run it in a GUI thread (as I assume it is due to the "Click" handler), then the `async` method will always resume on the GUI thread. I explain how this "context capturing" works in detail in my [`async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Short Answer

An `async` method fired by the `GUI` thread will execute on the same thread, whenever there are CPU operation *to* execute. Other `async` methods start running on the calling thread and continue on a `ThreadPool` thread.

### Long Answer

`SomeLongJobAsync` starts executing on the calling thread (the one that printed *"She'll be coming round the mountain"*) up until it reaches an `await`. Then a task is returned that represents the asynchronous operation + the continuation after it. When the *entire* operation is done the task will complete (unless it completes prematurely due to an exception or cancellation).

When `Task.Delay(1000)` itself is "executing" [there is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), because none is needed. And when finally `Task.Delay(1000)` ends, a thread *is* needed to resume on. Which thread it is depends on the [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) (by default there is *none* so the thread is a `ThreadPool` thread, but in a `GUI` application it's the singe GUI thread, more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24072676/885318)). That thread executes the rest of the code until it reaches another asynchronous point (i.e. another `await`) and so forth and so forth.

Comment: So for a GUI app, does the completion of `Task.Delay(1000)` still request a thread from thread pool, only to post `await` continuation to GUI thread via `SynchronizationContext.Post`?

Comment: @avo yes. Probably an I/O completion port thread like all I/O operations.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to realise is that async is not about creating threads, it's about replacing what used to be a blocking call by one that returns a continuation. A thread blocks when it is placed on a queue and it can then do nothing until the thing it blocked on becomes available (or a timeout or exception, etc). Blocking the UI thread is a terrible thing to do.

By contrast a continuation contains enough information captured at a point in the program for the thread to carry on ("continue") from that exact point at a later time. Obviously there is special stuff needed in all the Async calls for that to work, but that's what it does. It freezes the thread state into a continuation, parks that somewhere, returns immediately (so no blocking) and then (somehow) starts again from that state at a later time when the required information is available.

For that reason, you can assume that the work for both the async method and the "long job" will be done on the same thread, just not at the same time, and that the operating system will choose a good time to decide when to make those choices.

In practice there is a difference between threads that have a message pump (UI threads) and others, and there is the possibility of work being moved to a different thread, and there are various features in the `Task`, the `SynchronizationContext` and thread pools to support more advanced scenarios.

But I think the key to answering your question and for you to understand is this subtle use of something new called a continuation, and how it can capture the state of a program at one time for use later. Continuations have been used in functional languages for a long time, and are in some ways related to the concepts of futures and promises in other languages. Once you think in these terms you can forget about threads entirely.

Answer (score 1):

`SomeLongJobAsync` starts executing on the thread that called it, and if there is one, the current `SynchronizationContext` is saved in the state machine generated by the `await` mechanism.

After the first `await` completes, the continuation of the method is posted on the current `SynchronizationContext`. In a GUI app this means that the continuation executes on the UI thread. In a console app, there is no `SyncrhronizatonContext` so the continuation executes on a thread pool thread.

You can check this by printing out the `ManagedThreadId` of `Thread.CurrentThread` as your program executes. Consider this modified version of your code (which I ran from a console app on Linqpad):

```
private async void btnSlowPoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await DoItAsync();
}

private async Task<int> SomeLongJobAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        //ponder my existence for one second
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        Console.WriteLine("Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    return 42;
}

public async Task<int> DoItAsync()
{   
    Console.WriteLine("She'll be coming round the mountain, threadId = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Task<int> t = SomeLongJobAsync();  //<--On what thread does this execute?
    Console.WriteLine(" when she comes., threadId = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    return await t;
}

void Main()
{
    btnSlowPoke_Click(null, null);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Output from Console App:**

```
She'll be coming round the mountain, threadId = 21
Start SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 21
 when she comes., threadId = 21
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 11
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 11
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 11
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 11
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 11
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 12
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 12
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 12
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 12
```

As you can see the method started runnung on thread 21, but as each of the await completed it continued on a thread pool thread and not always the same one. In this case 11, 12. If I run this in a Windows Forms app the output is this:

**Output from Windows Forms App:**

```
She'll be coming round the mountain, threadId = 8
Start SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 8
 when she comes., threadId = 8
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 8
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 8
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 8
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 8
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 8
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 8
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 8
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 8
Continue SomeLongJobAsync, threadId = 8
```

Comment: This looks like a definitive answer to me, but it seems to disagree with the others. Withholding judgment until more discussion.

Comment: That's true only when there's no SynchronizationContext (for example in LinqPad), not in a GUI/ASP.Net threading model.

Answer (score 0):

It is executed on the same thread. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) explains:

> The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async method doesn't run on its own thread. The method runs on the current synchronization context and uses time on the thread only when the method is active. You can use Task.Run to move CPU-bound work to a background thread, but a background thread doesn't help with a process that's just waiting for results to become available.