# How to implement HttpMessageHandler in Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-4.5

In an ASP.NET 4.5 MVC 4 Web API project, I want to add a custom `HttpMessageHandler`. I've changed `WebApiConfig` class (in \App_Satrt\WebApiConfig.cs), as follows:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null,
            handler: new MyCustomizedHttpMessageHandler()
        );
    }
}
```

Then I developed `MyCustomizedHttpMessageHandler`:

```
public class MyCustomizedHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(
            new GenericIdentity("myuser"), new string[] { "myrole" });
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

        return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => request.CreateResponse());
    }
}
```

However, the request to the API (let's say  http://mylocalhost.com/api/values), always returns status code 200, without any data. I mean it never gets to ValuesController.cs's 'GET()' method.

What have I missed? How can I implement `HttpMessageHandler` properly?

PS: Have already read this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12030785/538387 , doesn't help me.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here you are creating a `HttpMessageHandler` which short circuits the request and doesn't let the request pass through the rest of the pipeline. Instead, you should create a `DelegatingHandler`.

Also there are 2 kinds of message handler pipelines in Web API. One is a regular pipeline in which all requests for all routes pass through and other where one could have message handlers specific to certain routes only.

1. Try to create a `DelegatingHandler` and add it to your `HttpConfiguration`'s list of message handlers:

   ```
   config.MessageHandlers.Add(new HandlerA())
   ```
2. If you want to add a route specific message handler, then you could do the following:

   ```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
               constraints: null,
               handler: 
                      HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(
                             new HttpControllerDispatcher(config), 
                             new DelegatingHandler[]{new HandlerA()})
               );
   ```

[This Web Api Poster](http://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf) shows the pipeline flow.

Comment: Thank you. Solution (1) works well. But number 2, `new HttpControllerDispatcher()` says: **System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments** - Update: I fixed your code. Thank you.

Comment: Please also add this part of Cuong Le's answer to your answere: **To write a custom message handler, you should derive from `System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler`.**

Comment: The link for the poster is broken.

Comment: in which file do we need to add the code: config.MessageHandlers.Add(new HandlerA())

Answer (score 16):

To write a custom message handler, you should derive from `System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler`

```
class CustomMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> 
      SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(
            new GenericIdentity("myuser"), new string[] { "myrole" });
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And call `base.SendAsync` to send the request to the inner handler.

Comment: @Cuonge Le - Thank you for the answer. After I replaced `CustomMessageHandler` with your code, it raises error on `return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);` saying:  **The inner handler has not been assigned.** . What I missed again?

Comment: @Counge Le - The combination of your answer and Kirran Chall's, has fixed the issue. Thank you again.

Comment: @Cuong Le what is the equivalent for .NET 4.0? I could not find DelegatingHandler for .NET .4... how can do messagehandling in 4.0. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I used @cuongle answer to solve my problem. Just with one addition. So I did not get "**The inner handler has not been assigned.**". Thank you @coungle.

```
public class CustomMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
        public CustomMessageHandler ()
        {
              //add this to solve "The inner handler has not been assigned"
               InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        }
    
        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> 
          SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Before request 
            IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(
                new GenericIdentity("myuser"), new string[] { "myrole" });
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
    
            var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    
            // After request when response arrives
            
            return result;
        }
}
```