# How come my Claims are not visible in my User in the controller? (ASP.NET WebAPI OWIN Self Hosted)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I setup my HttpListener to allow Basic and Anonymous authentication. I also add a new MessageHandler called AuthenticationHandler to my configuration.

```
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            var listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
            listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic | AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;

            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

           //...
            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthenticationHandler());

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
```

---

`AuthenticationHandler` is a `DelegatingHandler`. I set up my claims, identity and principal as below:

```
                if (validCredentials)
                {
                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod, AuthenticationMethods.Password),
                    };

                    var roles = user.Roles.ToString().Split(',');
                    // Make sure to add all the user's roles to the claims
                    claims.AddRange(roles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));

                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme);

                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new [] {identity});

                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

                    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
                }
```

If I check Thread.CurrentPrincipal in the debugger my principal has my identity and all the claims that I've added. All seems fine inside the DelegatingHandler, however these claims are not making their way to my controller.

In my controller I have a simple `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` attribute on a function. However, if I check the `User` in the debugger, the only claim listed is the username. So `[Authorize]` works, as does `[Authorize(Users="admin')]`, however, obviously role based authentication will not work. I could of course look the username up in the database and manually check the roles in the function, but that is clearly not the correct way of going about this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see this answer for a similar question [this user is also experiencing the same problem you mention](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12030785/3356508)

Comment: @CallbackKid I see but, I am self-hosted, so HttpContext is null. It must be something else in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OWIN, the principal must be set in the request like so:
`request.GetRequestContext().Principal = principal;`