# Mocking the claimsIdentity in test method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I have controller method which calls some other code and passes user info.

```
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyRecords([FromBody] myBody body,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
           //some logic;
           var user = GetUser();
           var ready = new CreateRecords(new Execute("Test"), new Contracts.Data.User(user.Id, user.Name));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _log.Error("Request failed", e);
            return base.InternalServerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static UserInfo GetUser()
    {
        if (!(Thread.CurrentPrincipal?.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity))
            return null;

        var name = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value ?? "";
        var userId = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        return null == userId ? null : new UserInfo(int.Parse(userId), name);
    }
```

Now i am writing unit tests agains that controller method and bit lost on how to pass user information since i dont have any constructor which accepts that information so how to mock this info in the unit test?

This is how the constructor of my controller looks like

```
 private readonly ILog _log;

    public MyTestController(ILog log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }
```

This is my test method

```
 [Test]
    public async Task TestMethod()
    {
        // Arrange
        
        var controller = new MyTestController(new Mock<ILog>().Object);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetUser()` reads the static property [`Thread.CurrentPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal), so if you want to manipulate what that static method returns, you have to write said property as well.

Luckily it's publicly-writable, so you can just do:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(
    new[] { 
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "FooName"), 
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "42") 
    }
));
```

And then perform the rest of your test.

See also: [How can I safely set the user principal in a custom WebAPI HttpMessageHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028604/how-can-i-safely-set-the-user-principal-in-a-custom-webapi-httpmessagehandler)