# Altering breeze query string in the controller before being processed

Tags: filter, controller, breeze

Scenario:  my app runs queries where the user id is used in many cases to filter what data the user can see.  The user id is an integer.  I don't want the user to be able to simply alter the query string and change the user ID parm to another # (and essentially assume another user's identity).  Through our authentication process, each request to the server includes a security token in the header, which was returned to the client when they logged in.  During the auth process, this token is stored on the server and is mapped to the user's user id.

What I would like to do is pull the token out of the header, do a lookup and get the user ID that is mapped to the token value (got that working), and then alter the query string to add the user ID.

So a request may come in as

```
http://localhost/api/app/customerlist
```

And after I get the user id, it may look like this

```
http://localhost/api/app/customerlist?$filter=userid%20eq%1234
```

And then continue on.

This is a simple scenario but illustrates my goal.  I am not able to add surrogate keys to the database and use a GUID or some other value as my filter column.  Pretty much stuck with the structure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the EntityQuery.withParameters method.  With it from the client you can take any query and add your user id filter to it.  Something like

```
 myQuery = myQuery.withParameters( { userId: 1234});
 myEntityManager.executeQuery(myQuery).then(...);
```

Or am I missing something.

Comment: It looks like your solution is client-based, is that right?  I need to alter the query string on the server.  Most of my users are not very technical, but if one of them got a hold of Fiddler, or similar, they could see that full URL with the filter being sent to the server.  They just might try altering the user id and seeing what comes back.  Through trial and error they may see data that is not for them to see.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side you can add any filters directly to whatever IQueryable is returned. If you use the Authorize attribute you can also access the user data via the "User" variable.

```
[BreezeController]
[Authorize]
public class NorthwindIBModelController : ApiController {

   [HttpGet]
   public IQueryable<Customer> CustomerList() {
     var userName = User.Identity.Name;

     var filter = filter on customers;
     var custs = ContextProvider.Context.Customers.Where({ some filter using userName});
   }

}
```

Also see:
[Passing username to Web Api methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705031/passing-username-to-web-api-methods-in-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: I think we're getting closer.  Will this work if there's already a filter?  So I have this being sent from the client:  htt://myapp/api/account?$filter=CustomerState%20eq%20'NY'&$orderby=AccountName.  I have a filter on CustomerState and and orderby.  Using your suggestion can I add the UserName filter, and keep the existing CustomerState filter, and order by?

Comment: Yes it will; Breeze starts with the IQueryable you provide on the server and then adds client side filters to it.