# ASP.NET Web API authentication always redirecting to login page

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

My ASP.NET MVC application is using Forms authentication with `[System.Web.Mvc.Authorize]` . I would like to use `[System.Web.Http.Authorize]` attribute to protect my Web API controller and because i'm calling it with `HttpClient` from my MVC controller I've have implemented a custom delegating handler like the one in the following post:

[ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API Authentication with Membership Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535075/asp-net-mvc-4-web-api-authentication-with-membership-provider/11536349#11536349)

When debugging i can see that the principal is set and the user has right roles but still I'm being redirected to the login page?

So basically when i log in and visit the WebAPI action with browser everything works (as would if i use AJAX from my views), but when i use `HttpClient` inside my controller (which i know is a new request with different context) with Basic authentication and set the principal i always get redirected.

I've tried so many solutions/workarounds and i'm always redirected to login page.
Anyone has an idea.

Comment: So, when you have logged in, did you verify in the delegating handler that the login cookie is sent for each request. If so, it should authorize you

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explanation:

[System-web-http-authorize x System-web-mvc-authorize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152109/system-web-http-authorize-versus-system-web-mvc-authorize)

Another interesting point is you use your custom authorization. I did it and it worked. Following example:

[Customized authorization Mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942042/customized-authorization-attribute-in-mvc-4-with-roles)

Good Luck