# Existing MVC4 Project to share data with Winform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC4 internet solution which uses the following setup

- N Tier Application with Repository Design
- Authentication etc all decoupled from UI and on DAL Layer (Accessed via SecurityRepository)
- Uses SimpleAuthentication in background

I have been asked to add a WebAPI project to the solution so I can share the datasource, purely for reading some data out to a Winform application internally.

Is it possible to still decorate the Controllers in the API with `[Authorize]` and call the `SecurityRepository.Login` method to authenticate a winform? Winforms don't use cookies so not sure how I would supply a token and manage access via roles. I want it to authenticate in the background and not have a login page, ideally seamless to the end user we have switched the current Winform app datasource to point to this WebAPI.

[Edit]

For future searchers, look here too: [ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API Authentication with Membership Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535075/asp-net-mvc-4-web-api-authentication-with-membership-provider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change your Authentication for WebApi. The easiest way is to implement token autentication. There is a simple article on Steves Coding Blog about [Basic Authentication with Asp.Net WebAPI](http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/basic-authentication-with-asp-net-webapi/)

Comment: This has given me some good ideas on a custom auth attribute.