# How to use authentication with MVC Web API?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to configure authentication for an MVC Web API that is accessed by another MVC site. I have tried many things in the web.config, many suggestions from SO. However all to no avail.

I am using the following code from the MVC website:

```
var web = new WebClient();
web.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
web.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

I then use that web client to invoke methods on the other MVC site that only contains API controllers. Without authentication everything works like it should but I can't get authentication to work. When making the request I get an exception that a 401 is returned (which is a good thing if you ask me but it doesn't appear to send the credentials).

I also tried to put the username and password in the URL but that didn't work either.

Here is the relevant section of the web.config file of the Web API site:

```
    <authentication>
      <forms 
        cookieless="UseUri"
        enableCrossAppRedirects="false">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
          <user name="site" password="XYZ123!"/>
        </credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

I want to put a single username/password there just to make sure that it is the website that is invoking methods. My API controllers have the 'Authorize' attribute btw.

My question is: how can I add authentication to the Web API site so that I can invoke methods on it using authentication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Basic authentication. You can create a AuthorizationAttribute that validates the username/password in the Authorization header and returns a 401 response when not authorized.

See [this post](http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-membership-provider/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You could use basic authentication instead of forms authentication as I illustrated in [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11536349/29407). There are also other ways of authentication possible. For example token based authentication as shown in [this blog post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/630986/Cross-Platform-Authentication-With-ASP-NET-Web-API).